# jquery stop method causing ie6 to stack overflow

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have six menu options in my webapp, and when the user hovers over a link (ul>li>a) I switch an image to show a context relevant photo, and I fade the image in and out.  However, I noticed that when a user moved their mouse quickly between links, the queue didn't process properly and the user would often be hovering over a link and have an old image displayed from the previous hover.  After a bit of reading, it appeared the right thing to do was to use the stop() method, but when I try and implement it, ie6 reports a stack overflow.

Here's my old code (which has the old image problem):

```
if(webImage != 'img/template/slide_web.png') {
                        $('#slide img').fadeOut(function() {
                            $(this).load(function() {$(this).fadeIn(); });
                            $(this).attr('src','img/template/slide_web.png');
                        });
```

And here's my new code (which resolves the old problem, but causes ie6 to stack overflow on the first line):

```
if(webImage != 'img/template/slide_web.png') {
                        $('#slide img').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function() {
                            $(this).load(function() {$(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn(); });
                            $(this).attr('src','img/template/slide_web.png');
                        });
```

Am I implementing the stop() method incorrectly?  Or is there another way to avoid the jQuery fade queue from losing it's place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$(this).load(function() {$(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn(); });
```

You're binding a *new* `.load()` handler (albeit the same function) *each* time you're fading out, so you need to either bind it once, outside of this scope, or [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) it, like this:

```
$(this).unbind('load').load(function() {$(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn(); });
```

Without that, it's trying to run those load handlers all at once, something it can't handle, effectively, it's executing `.stop(true, true).fadeIn()` *many* times in a row.

Comment: Thank you, that's made things a little more stable, however I'm now getting stack overflow in ie6 whenever I 'interrupt' the fading of one image by starting another.  Which brings me back to my thoughts about the stop() function.

Comment: For now I've just replaced my code with this plugin, works fine :) http://www.hieu.co.uk/blog/index.php/imageswitch/

Comment: @Nick - (Hi other Nick!) It depends on the effect, but I think you'd want `.stop(true)` in this case, not to try and finish the current animation first, which is what the second argument does :)